# change form based on drop down menu selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm having trouble finding javascript, HTML and/or CSS code that'll change the form based on the drop down menu. For example, the form is for adding a property and the drop down menu selections are single family, condo, apartment but they each have their own set of text boxes, menus and radio buttons. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try some code first, and when you get stuck post a question about the particular issue.  You're likely to get more help than a question which is really asking others to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

What I have understand from your query is that , you have a from with some fields and you have a dropdown and you want that when ever your change selection in dropdown the form fields values must change accordingly right ?

If that is the issue , then it is very simple , first catch onSelectionChange event of dropdown and try to get selected value and once you get the selected value fill form fields by accessing them accordingly in a condition.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I actually already had a piece of code I was fumbling with `(http://jsfiddle.net/CYzsY/)` for this question and it looks like its not working for me because its based on jQuery 1.7.1 and I'm linking to 1.10.2 in my code. Will make a new post accordingly. Thanks everyone!